On the definition of smooth bundle maps
I will denote a fiber bundle $p: E\to B$ by $(E,B,p)$ where $E$ is the total space, and $B$ is the base space. Recently, I learned about the notion of bundle maps, i.e., maps between two fiber bundles. A tuple $(f, \overline{f})$ is a bundle map from $(E,B,p)$ to $(E',B',p')$, if $f: B \to B'$ and $\overline{f}: E\to E'$ are such that the corresponding diagram commutes. Next, the definition says that the bundle map $(f,\overline{f})$ is called smooth if the maps $f,\overline f$ are smooth, and $\overline f$ is a diffeomorphism on each fiber.
$\require{AMScd}$
$$
\begin{CD}
  E   @>\overline{f}>>  E' \\
  @VpVV                @Vp'VV \\
  B   @>f>>            B'
\end{CD}
$$
I'm trying to unpack the second part of the definition. To require the maps $f,\overline f$ to be smooth is natural, but why is the condition that $\overline f$ be a diffeomorphism on each fiber important? Can we come up with fiber bundles $(E,B,p)$ and $(E',B',p')$ and maps $f: B \to B'$ and $\overline{f}: E\to E'$ such that the diagram commutes, but $\overline f$ is not a diffeomorphism on some fiber?
I'm new to the concept of fiber bundles and I think I have not worked with enough examples to see what the right definition should be. Is $\overline f$ at least a homeomorphism on fibers if the bundle map is not necessarily smooth? Thanks!

I don't think it must be a diffeomorphism. Maybe there is something wrong about the definition.

One certainly has smooth bundle maps between bundles with different ranks. Where are you finding this?

@TedShifrin This comes from the whiteboard of a class I am taking.

Either you’ve misunderstood or your teacher has adopted a very unusual approach. It does not allow for (smooth or even holomorphic) exact sequences of vector bundles on a fixed base manifold, for example.

I'm guessing by the same reasoning, it is not necessary that $\overline f$ be a homeomorphism on fibers in the general case. Right? @TedShifrin

The fibers may well have different dimensions. In the case of vector bundles, the map should be linear in each fiber.

@TedShifrin It struck me that we might be misinterpreting this. I think the statement is about $\overline f$ being a diffeomorphism between a fiber and its image under $\overline f$. The fibers of (E',B',p') should not be relevant, I guess.

Nope. Because the diagram commutes, the image is contained in the fiber of $E’$.

Yes, this is unnecessarily restrictive definition which does not allow for subbundles and quotient bundles. You should ask your instructor for their reason, I do not see any.

The diffeomorphism part is probably said in the definition because usually fibre bundle maps are required to be fibre preserving, that is, they map fibres to fibres. It is not a requirement to define a bundle map (smooth or not) but it is desirable. In the case of non-smooth maps the condition would translate as $\overline{f}$ being a homeomorphism on the fibres.
